# How do I run this file?

Tags: emulation

I downloaded BasiliskII from emaculation.com for Linux but I don't know how to run it. The file name is BasiliskII_X_Linux_13_09_2010 and when I double click on it, nothing happens. Sorry if it is a dumb question I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have it checked as run as executable and when I do the `file` command it says it is a 32-bit LSB executable. I have unzipped the file

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That's too little information provided. Double click the file and check the type of it, and if *Allow executing file as a program* is marked. [Edit] your question with that info

Comment: This BasiliskII_X_Linux_13_09_2010 is a __zip__ so unzip it. And what do you need the file for ?

Comment: It's an emulator

Comment: I have unzipped the file

Comment: Yes I see that, let me run it in a VM and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried but as I can see its not as simple as just running that you will need to consult with their [forum](http://www.emaculation.com/forum/)